# OpenCV Stitching, C++ - Unhandled exception

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv, opencv-stitching

Im trying to stitch three images together. To do this, I chose OpenCV 2.4.10 and Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express. 
The Images are 1500x1500px and in CV_8UC3 when read.
Im building for 32bit and already got a few other things working with OpenCV, so I guess the project is set up correctly with paths etc..

The odd thing is, that I get this error only **sometimes**, and only if I try to stitch **more than two images**.

Here the error message:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x5841dcaa in Stitching Test.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000004.
```

After that I get automatically to line 99 of "Chores.cpp" or line 189 of "TaskCollection.cpp", so i think thats the source of the error. (Path C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\crt\src)

And here the code:

```
#include <iostream>

//OPENCV
#include <opencv2\core\core.hpp>
#include <opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp>
//OPENCV STITCHING
#include <opencv2\stitching\stitcher.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(){
    Mat panoramaImage;
    vector<Mat> inputImages;

    inputImages.push_back(imread("../../V1.bmp"));
    inputImages.push_back(imread("../../V2.bmp"));
    inputImages.push_back(imread("../../V3.bmp"));

    Stitcher stitcher = Stitcher::createDefault();
    Stitcher::Status stitcherStatus = stitcher.stitch(inputImages, panoramaImage);

    imshow("Stitching Result", panoramaImage); 
    waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

Someone got a suggestion?

Comment: since no one seems to have an answer, I filed a [bug report](http://code.opencv.org/issues/4236)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue solved -  I found out that I had "_DEBUG;" in my preprocessor definitions while running on release. 
Still very odd that the error only occured sometimes...